# bootstrapのタブ内で要素を横並びに出来ない

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

はじめまして。menu-image要素とmenu-text要素を横並びにしたいのですが、できずに困っています。初歩的な質問だとは思いますが、自身で解決できずに困っています。宜しくお願い致します。

```css
.tab-pane {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-tab {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-image {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu-image img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.name {
  width: 50%;
}

.price {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#set-menu" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">定食・鍋</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#baked-menu" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">焼き物</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="set-menu">
      <div class="menu-image">
        <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="menu-text">
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">A定食</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">B定食</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">C定食</p>
          <p class="price">930円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">D鍋</p>
          <p class="price">1050円</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" tab-pane" id="baked-menu">
      <div class="menu-image">
        <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="menu-text">
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">D</p>
          <p class="price">650円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">E</p>
          <p class="price">950円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">F</p>
          <p class="price">650円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">G</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">H</p>
            <p class="price">1450円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">I</p>
            <p class="price">350円</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap により、`.tab-pane` に設定したスタイルが上書きされているためです。

`.tab-pane` には、現在アクティブなタブを表示させ、それ以外を非表示にするために、`display: block`, `display: none` のどちらかが適用されています。そのため、`.tab-pane` の `display` プロパティを常に flex に設定すると、前述したタブとしての機能が失われてしまいます。

そこで、`.tab-pane` に `.active` クラスが付与されたときのみ `display` プロパティを上書きします。こうすることで、タブとしての機能は維持されます。

```css
.tab-content>.tab-pane.active { /* 変更 */
  display: flex;
}

.menu-tab {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-image {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu-image img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.name {
  width: 50%;
}

.price {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#set-menu" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">定食・鍋</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#baked-menu" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">焼き物</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="set-menu">
      <div class="menu-image">
        <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="menu-text">
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">A定食</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">B定食</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">C定食</p>
          <p class="price">930円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">D鍋</p>
          <p class="price">1050円</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" tab-pane" id="baked-menu">
      <div class="menu-image">
        <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="menu-text">
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">D</p>
          <p class="price">650円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">E</p>
          <p class="price">950円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">F</p>
          <p class="price">650円</p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-tab">
          <p class="name">G</p>
          <p class="price">1350円</p>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">H</p>
            <p class="price">1450円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">I</p>
            <p class="price">350円</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

もしくは、`.tab-pane` の子要素に `display: flex` を適用した `div` 要素を作り、その中に`.menu-image` と `.menu-text` を入れることでも解決出来ます。このようにすることでも、タブとしての機能が失われることなく、スタイルを適用することが出来ます。

```css
.tab-pane-content { /* 変更 */
  display: flex;
}

.menu-tab {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-image {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.menu-image img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.name {
  width: 50%;
}

.price {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#set-menu" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">定食・鍋</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#baked-menu" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">焼き物</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="set-menu">
      <div class="tab-pane-content">
        <div class="menu-image">
          <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="menu-text">
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">A定食</p>
            <p class="price">1350円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">B定食</p>
            <p class="price">1350円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">C定食</p>
            <p class="price">930円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">D鍋</p>
            <p class="price">1050円</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" tab-pane" id="baked-menu">
      <div class="tab-pane-content">

        <div class="menu-image">
          <img src="img/menu-img.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="menu-text">
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">D</p>
            <p class="price">650円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">E</p>
            <p class="price">950円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">F</p>
            <p class="price">650円</p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-tab">
            <p class="name">G</p>
            <p class="price">1350円</p>
            <div class="menu-tab">
              <p class="name">H</p>
              <p class="price">1450円</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-tab">
              <p class="name">I</p>
              <p class="price">350円</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```